# Struggling to expand div based on dynamic data from database (comments feature)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have been struggling with this common social networking feature for quite some time. What I am trying to do is to expand the div to display comments, I'm sure you know what I am talking about.

Each `post` a user sends is automatically echo'd with an anchor link `Comments`. As mentioned, when this link is clicked, it will simply expand the div displaying all comments assigned to that `thought_id`.

Even if there are no comments assigned to the post, I still want the div to expand to display a text field so any user can post a comment, preferably echo this:

```
<?php
<form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
      <table style='width:850px;'>
           <tr>
               <td><textarea name='msg' rows='2' maxlength='255' cols='80' placeholder=' add your comment...'></textarea></td>
               <td><input type='submit' name='send' value='Share'/> </td>
           </tr>
       </table>
</form>
?>
```

**Here is what I have so far**:

```
<script language="javascript">
    var id = <?php echo $thought_id; ?>;
    function toggle(id) {
        var ele = document.getElementById("toggleComment" + id);
        if (ele.style.display == "block") {
            ele.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            ele.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
</script>
```

And here is where the `comments` anchor link is found. Since it is quite lengthy, I have reduced the echo's content to only the relevant code:

```
echo "<div class='message_wrapper'>

        <div class='where_msg_displayed'>
            <div class='more_options' style='float: right;'>

                // Options, and display picture of the user who posted the 
                // thought can be found here.

            </div>
        </div>

    <div class='where_details_displayed'> 
        <div class='mini_nav' style='float: right;'>

            // Below is the comments anchor link.
            <a onclick='return toggle($thought_id);' style='padding-left: 5px;'> Comments ($num_of_comments) </a> 

        </div>  

            // I expect the following piece below to every comment assigned to the thought_id in the database.
        <div id='toggleComment$thought_id' class='new_comment' style='display:none;'>
            <br/> $comment_posted_by said: $comment_body
        </div>

    </div>
</div>";
```

**Other Infomation:**

- `$thought_id` is the id of the though the user posts. (table `user_thoughts`, column `id`).
- I have another table called `user_comments`, which stores all comments and links it to the `thought` it is assigned to by `post_id`.
- At the moment, nothing happens when I click `comments`.

Comment: You could change the visibility of the css class through that js, that'd be simpler I think

Comment: if you are using `jQuery` library in your script, then why don't you use simply `.toggle()`

Comment: Have you checked that it is not a CSS issue? Like some other element is on top of the A link preventing the event to be fired. You could check it with Chrome Dev Tools or similar, just to test the actual element is really clicked. You could try to replace with some other element, like button or create console.log if the click is handled.

Comment: @TeroTolonen - Yes, I know the `<a>` is being fired because the cursor changes when I hover over the link. The think is, when you hover over a anchor tag, you expect to see the hand cursor, when I hover over the anchor tag, I get the text cursor (the one that looks like an I)?

Comment: @Freddy you get the text cursor because your link doesn't have an `href` attribute.

Comment: @Freddy Also, did you first try to check if your javascript function toggle() is ever called when you click? You can do that by adding a `console.log('toggle clicked');` or `alert('clicked');` first line inside toggle().

Comment: @YannMilin - I have just added `alert("clicked");` after the line `function toggle(id) {` and nothing seems to happen, I don't think the anchor tag is clickable, because, well, as you said, there is no href?

Comment: is using jQuery Ok .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/z0w7fa5e/1/) is a working example of what you want to achieve based on your code.

I had to strip the php part off because jsfiddle doesn't interpret it, so next is your code including the PHP bit.

I assumed that you have jQuery loaded as you added the jquery tag to the question.

It's complicated to know why what you tried doesn't work because we're missing important bit such as: how do you load your content into the DOM? dynamically or not (ajax?)

### HTML/PHP

```
<div class='message_wrapper'>
    <div class='where_msg_displayed'>
        <div class='more_options' style='float: right;'>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='where_details_displayed'>
        <div class='mini_nav' style='float: right;'>
            <a href="#" class="toggle-comment" data-id="<?=$thought_id?>" style='padding-left: 5px;'>  Comments (<?=$num_of_comments?>) </a>
        </div>
        <div id='toggleComment<?=$thought_id?>' class='new_comment' style='display:none;'>
            <br/> <?=$comment_posted_by?> said: <?=$comment_body?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

- Your link was missing an href attribute, which is mandatory for it to be displayed properly. So we set it to the commonly used "#" which means blank anchor. We will then need to catch the click event on this link and prevent its default action so we don't see that ugly # in our url
- You should avoid storing big chunks of html in a php var and then `echo` it but use html templates instead.
- You should avoid mixing PHP and javascript like this line in your code that assign a php var into a js one `var id = <?php echo $thought_id; ?>;`
  Instead, You can store your thought_ids as a data attribute of your links and easily fetch them using jQuery's [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) later.

### Javascript

```
$(function() {
    $("a.toggle-comment").on("click", function(event) {
        // prevents browser to go to href's #
        event.preventDefault();

        // uses Jquery's data() function to get comment id from link's data-id attribute
        var id = $(this).data('id');

        // get element by id and toggle display
        var ele = document.getElementById("toggleComment" + id);
        $(ele).toggle();
    });
});
```

Here I got rid of your toggle() function and replaced it with a handler function using jQuery's [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) that get called each time we click on a link that has the `toggle-comment` CSS class. It has the advantage of working on dynamically added content after the page is loaded. jQuery's on() documentation page does a great job explaining this (and the deprecated live() page too)

Notice that you will need to add this `toggle-comment` class to every of your `Comments (X)` links

If you are new to jQuery, you should consider reading [this page](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) to understand what the first line does and why you need it. (referring to enclosing your code into `$(function() {...});`)

`event.preventDefault();` tells the browser to not perform its default behaviour when clicking on the link (which is go to that link and would append # to the address bar)

`$(this).data('id');` reads put the clicked link (this) into a jQuery object and use data() to get the value of its data-id attribute, which is set to $thought_id

### CSS issue update

See my [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z0w7fa5e/2/) for your CSS issue, I removed the float inline styles and positioned div.mini_nav using absolute positioning relative to message_wrapper.
I think that this issue is not related to the original question and should be asked in another one.

Comment: Thank you! I have got majority of it working now. The thing is, the comment is appearing to expand upwards, whereas I want the div to expand downwards. For example, in your fiddle, when the link is clicked, the bottom of the div stays in place, but it expands upwards. Also this: `  <div id='toggleComment1' class='new_comment' style='display:none;'>` doesn't seem to work for me, i.e. nothing happens/loads, but when I have `<div id='toggleComment$thought_id' class='new_comment' style='display:none;'>`, the comment shows? Just thinking this may contribute to the expanding issue.

Comment: You're right I forgot to put back $thought_id in my answer, it's mandatory since otherwise every block would have the same id. I edited my answer to reflect this. For the "expand upwards" issue, it only has to do with CSS. I didn't look this part at all. My first guess is this this is caused by the use of float.

Comment: Yann, thank you very much! you have really helped me and the feature is now working cleanly. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**PHP Code as per OP's**

```
<?php
$thought_id         = 1;
$num_of_comments    = 10;
$comment_posted_by  = "Me";
$comment_body       = "test comment body";
//hard coded above vars to achieve assumptions

echo "<div class='message_wrapper'>
        <div class='where_msg_displayed'>
            <div class='more_options' style='float: right;'>
                // Options, and display picture of the user who posted the 
                // thought can be found here.
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class='where_details_displayed'> 
        <div class='mini_nav' style='float: right;'>
            // Below is the comments anchor link.
            <a href='' onclick='return toggle($thought_id);' style='padding-left: 5px;'> Comments ($num_of_comments) </a> 
        </div>  
        // I expect the following piece below to every comment assigned to the thought_id in the database.
        <div id='toggleComment$thought_id' class='new_comment' style='display:none;'>
            <br/> $comment_posted_by said: $comment_body
        </div>
    </div>
</div>";
?>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script language="javascript">
    var id = <?php echo $thought_id; ?>;
    function toggle(id) {
        var ele = document.getElementById("toggleComment" + id);
        if (ele.style.display == "block") {
            ele.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            ele.style.display = "block";
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

The above code worked for me, as per single record.

**Now as you have tagged your question under `jQuery`**

you could simply use

```
$(".message_wrapper .mini_nav a[href!='']").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next().toggle();
});
```

Comment: I have altered my code to adopt to the above. But again, nothing seems to happen when I click on the `comments` anchor link. I'm beginning to think there's an issue with the anchor link since it isn't performing any action?

Comment: It is better, if you try out a fiddle, so that, I would know where you are going wrong.. On my answered ones, both works for me..

Comment: Here you go - https://jsfiddle.net/vrqsz3ev/. This is my first fiddle, so apologies if anything is incorrect.

Comment: @Freddy mate one thing you need to do again here for me, fiddle doesn't support php vars and executions, so you need to hard code the values (means how your html and js looks like in your webpage source after being populated with any server sided script)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the `<details>` HTML tag which acts as a disclosure triangle.

```
<details>
    <summary>View comments</summary>
    <ul>
        <li>You comments</li>
        <li>You comments</li>
        <li>You comments</li>
    </ul>
</details>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details

The only issue is that it is not supported by the lovely IE browsers.

Answer (score 0):

> **If I understand your question correctly , this is what you are looking for** 
>   https://jsfiddle.net/vrqsz3ev/7/

```
<div class='message_wrapper'>
 <div class="main-msg-container">
    <div class='where_msg_displayed'>
          <input type="hidden" id="msg-id" value="1">
          <div class='more_options'>    
          MESSAGE1
          </div>
          <div class='mini_nav'>
           <button class="open-comment">comments</button>
         </div>
    </div>
```

```
   <div class="hide-mess-details">
     <div class='where_details_displayed'> 
        <div id='toggleComment1'class='new_comment msg-id-1'>
           sachin said: Hii guysss (cmt of msg 1)
        </div>

        <form action='' class="comment-form"method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <textarea name='msg' placeholder=' add your     comment...'></textarea>
    <input type='submit' name='send' value='Share'/> 
       </form>

    </div>
 </div>

</div>
```

> I made it using **jQuery** 
>   
> Some of the **things to note** while looking into the **code** is

1. Uses the concept of flexbox in css3 to style it.
2. if you click on the `share` button only the comment of the respective message gets updated . For checking I added a message id along with the form when `comment` button is clicked .**for checking purpose I added an alert (message id of the respective messages)** if you click the `share button`
3. Now you can add your messages under `.where_msg_displayed` using php
4. display all the comments under `.where_details_displayed` (if you want to , you can add details under there respective messages -**little edit is needed**)

> If you are continuing with this code , with little edits you can achieve the above requirements .